# Getting error while setting IP Address to firewall using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created a function in Powershell to get IP Address from an endpoint and I want to add them in the AS firewall. The function is as stated below:

```
function getIPAddress() {

$egressName = "xyz." + $envName + ".abc.com"  
$response = Resolve-DnsName $egressName 

$ips = @()
foreach($ip in $response.IPAddress) {        
    $block = New-Object PsObject -Property @{description=$egressName; IPAddress=$ip}
    $ips+=$block
}

$ips = $ips | Sort-Object description, IPAddress

#Write-Host "IP Address: $($ips.IPAddress)"
#$ips.IPAddress

return $ips.IPAddress
```

}

I am calling the above function in another function and I want to add the IP addresses into the AS Firewall. Below is a part of the function:

```
function firewallAccessFunction {
    $rules = @()  
    $egressIpAddresses = getIPAddressFromEgress;
    Write-Host "Ip Address Generated from egress: $($egressIpAddresses[0])"
    if ($envName -eq "dev") {
        $rule4 = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallRule -FirewallRuleName "a" -RangeStart 1.1.1.1 -RangeEnd 2.2.2.2
        $rule5 = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallRule -FirewallRuleName "b" -RangeStart 1.1.1.1 -RangeEnd 2.2.2.2
                                          
        $rules = $rule4, $rule5         

        Write-Host "Adding egress IP Addresses to firewall: " 
        $counter = 1
        foreach ($egress in $egressIpAddresses) {

            Write-Host "Adding IP $($egress) into AS firewall"
            $egressIPRule = "eIPRule"
            $eIPRule += $counter
            $eIPRule = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallRule -FirewallRuleName $eIPRule -RangeStart e -RangeEnd e
            #Write-Host "eIPRule getType() : $($eIPRule)"
            #$rules.Add($eIPRule)
            $rules += $eIPRule
            #Write-Host "Rules: $($rules)"
            $counter += 1
        }
                                
        if ($vmIP -ne "0.0.0.0") {
            Write-Host "Added VM $vmIP to AS Firewall"
            $ruleVM = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallRule -FirewallRuleName "VM" -RangeStart $vmIP -RangeEnd $vmIP
            $rules += $ruleVM
        }
        $rules | % {
            $ipRuleList += $_
        }
        $ipRuleList = addRefreshIp $ipRuleList $envName
        $config = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallConfig -EnablePowerBIService -FirewallRule $ipRuleList

    } 

    "Set-AzAnalysisServicesServer:" + $asServerFullName + "; RG:" + $rg
    Write-Host "Config Variable: $($config)"
    Set-AzAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $asServerFullName -FirewallConfig $config -Tag $resourceGroupPolicy
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Set-AzAnalysisServicesServer: 
ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $asServerFullName -FirewallConfig $config ...
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FirewallConfig'.
```

Can I please get help on this? Thanks.

Comment: The parameter order? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.analysisservices/set-azanalysisservicesserver?view=azps-10.2.0 `-name` needs to be position 0 and `-ResourceGroupName` needs to be position 1 (`-FirewallConfig` is named so that's fine), so if you swap the order of `-Name and `-ResourceGroupName` does that make a difference?

Comment: @KeithLangmead: I tried it, it is giving the same error.

Comment: Maybe you Az.AnalysisServices PowerShell module is corrupted. Try moving to a previous version or updating to the newest version if you're not already there. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.AnalysisServices/1.1.4

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. It turned out that I had made a silly mistake. The $ sign is missing in   $eIPRule = New-AzAnalysisServicesFirewallRule -FirewallRuleName $eIPRule -RangeStart e -RangeEnd e line for e variable. When I added it, it started working.